# Laravel 8.0 419 PAGE EXPIRED on PayPal Api Create order

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am trying to call the PayPal server to set up the transaction but it returns a 419 PAGE EXPIRED error on the console.

PayPal create order script

```
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/create-payment', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },
```

Laravel Route

```
Route::post('/create-payment', [PayPalController::class, 'create_payment'])->name('create-payment');
```

Controller

```
public function create_payment()
    {

      $order = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $order->prefer('return=representation');

        $order->body = array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>
                array(
                    'return_url' => '/pages/orders',
                    'cancel_url' => '/pages/orders'
                ),
            'purchase_units' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'amount' =>
                                array(
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '420.00'
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
        try {
            $result = $this->client->execute($order);
            return $result;
        }
        catch(HttpException $ex) {
            print_r($ex->getMessage());
        }

   }
```

Blade

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

I know I need to add @csrf but where?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CSRF verification enabled by default in Laravel. so either you need to pass crsf token or skip that route from verification middleware.

#### Option 1

Add this route to csrf verification middleware except array.

```
App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

```php
protected $except = [
    "create-payment"
];
```

#### Option 2

Add this in your page head.

```html
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and this in script

```js
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think even you can override script from paypal without disabling csrf token .

```
<script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
       // X-CSRF-TOKEN is also required to add in request, otherwise you will not be able to access the createorder url
        paypal.Buttons({
            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                return fetch('http://yoursite.com/createorder', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.result.id;
                });
            },
            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                var _token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                return fetch('http://yoursite.com/captureorder/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    // Three cases to handle:
                    //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                    //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                    //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show a success / thank you message
                    // Your server defines the structure of 'orderData', which may differ
                    var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
                    if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                        // Recoverable state, see: "Handle Funding Failures"
                        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                        return actions.restart();
                    }
                    if (errorDetail) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                        if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                        if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                        // Show a failure message
                        return alert(msg);
                    }
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + orderData.result.payer.name.given_name);
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

Ref:http://findnerd.com/list/view/Paypal-Checkout-REST-api-integration-in-Laravel-5-7-with-smart-payment-buttons/74304/

Ref:https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server